Damage mitigation perk on a species?
I've been bored lately and decided to fall into the rabbit-hole of home-brewing a playable species for D&D and had a bit of a quandary.
I was trying to think up an odd version of a slime-creature and I liked the idea of making them resistant to non-magical melee damage, but the whole "Takes half damage" felt a bit much.
Would it be overpowered to give them a -1 damage to basic non-magical sources of slashing and piercing instead?
At first I thought it didn't sound too bad, but the fact that I've never seen any other race with anything like that as an ability had me concerned.

If you do it will be important to clarrify how that interacts with resistance, If hit by an attck that does 10 damage would a barbarian slime girl take (5-1) 4 damge or (9/2) 5 damage. that is does it cmoe before or after resistance. It has a bigger effect if after.

For your latter option, how would you compare that with half the feat Heavy Armor Master? One point always, instead of three points conditionally?

@John 9/2 is 4.5, so you'd take 4 damage either way. It would make a difference with -2 damage, for (10-2)/2 = 4 vs (10/2)-2 = 3. Good point otherwise.

@matszwecja right I forgot 5E stupid round down rule, but the point still stands even if my example was flawed.  it still matters with things like stacked resistance and halved damage, you need to clarify the math.

I'm not sure what you question is exactly. Do you want us to tell you examples of damage mitigation features on 5e races (I would know of atleast one) or are you asking to review a homebrew/houserule? If the latter is the case please tag your question with the respective tag and perhaps make what is to be reviewed stand out in its own sections in your question.

Sorry, to correct myself I was thinking instead of resistance, so if I received 10 damage it would become 9, or if something only hit me for 1 damage it would just bounce off, or into me harmlessly.
As for Heavy Weapons Master, perhaps feats that also mitigate damage like this does cancel this one out?
Maybe I'm just better with asking for damage resistance instead, I just liked the idea of the player being a bit oblivious to minor sources of damage and wondering why there's suddenly an extra arrow or such floating around inside them for comedic effect.

@TreeSpawned Err, both? My apologies, Its my first post and I'm not entirely sure of how to ask for help yet.

That's really on us. Someone should have said, Welcome to the stack! I see you've got that shiny badge for taking the [tour], and if you need any additional help, feel free to visit [help]. I think that people are mostly confused as there isn't really a concrete question we can answer. Right now, you're giving us an idea that you've had and expressed some concerns, but without a specific question, we would simply be guessing what you're after. I would maybe add something like "Are there any races that I'm not aware of that have this, and if not, what kind of balance issues would this cause?"
